# Airbnb vs booking.com near Oxford?

Tags: airbnb, oxford, booking.com

My wife and I are going to attend a symposium at Oxford University for a few days this September. The host is offering £205 on-campus accommodation for two nights. I'm not quite familiar with this place but I feel its a little bit expensive. The hotels nearby have a similar price level. I would like to know if this is indeed expensive and also what other options do I have.

In particular, as I have only experience with booking.com and not Airbnb, I could use some suggestion considering these two particular choices. booking.com's offerings range from £100+ to £4xx/night; Airbnb's offerings seem much cheaper (as low as £57/night).

How about the http://www.spareroom.co.uk/?

Comment: spareroom.co.uk is for long term houseshares/lodging. It's very good at that, but of little interest to travellers.

Comment: Around GBP100/night in Oxford city centre is a pretty decent price. All depends if you want to be in the city itself, or if you're happy with a 15-20 minute bus ride in from the suburbs

Comment: £50 per person per night is not too bad for England, cheaper options will be available a bit farther away. Oxford is on the train line and has bus lines as well.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question is difficult to answer because we don't really know what you want or expect from your hotel. It is possible to economize in Oxford but you may find you are in quite a downmarket kind of place.

If you are paying yourself, I would say that the hotels are quite expensive for what they offer, even compared to central London for example. I think it is simply a lack of competition in Oxford. So yes the prices are naturally high.

Maybe you can save money with Air BnB. If you stay in a place far away from the town centre, there is plentiful public transportation and cars are really difficult to use in central Oxford.

If you did not study at Oxford/Cambridge, it might be worth staying in the college accommodation to try it!

(Oxford University has no campus, the University and college buildings are spread out all over town.)

Comment: Thanks Calchas. The host's offering is as I quote: "Residential Fee £205 - includes single en‐suite student bed & breakfast accommodation on the nights of 9 and 10 September at St Anne’s College, Oxford and a conference dinner on the night of 10 September". It seems I have no choice but to go with their offering. This is possibly the cheapest choice, since the conference dinner costs £55.00...

Comment: @TroyWoo That price is actually pretty good for Oxford. I thought you meant £205/night!

Comment: Since it's difficult to answer you should vote to close it.

Comment: If you are offered £205 for two nights, including breakfast and conference dinner, then take it, it's a great deal.

Comment: @DJClayworth You are right......I think so too....XD